# How to insert null value to hierarchyid data type in SQL server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I tried to insert null values in table1 containing a column of data type ' ' 'hierarchyid'which throwed me the below error.

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "hierarchyid": 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.HierarchyIdException: 24001: SqlHierarchyId.Parse failed because the input string 'NULL' is not a valid string representation of a SqlHierarchyId node.
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.HierarchyIdException: at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId.Parse(SqlString input)
```

Is it possible to insert null values to this column or is there any alternate way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to insert `DBNull.Value` into the column, not the string "null".